# VS Code Python Extension: Settings for Linter

Tags: visual-studio-code, flake8, vscode-python

I'm using flake8 and normally, you can suppress warnings by warning type.

For example, the following will suppress error groups E1 & E23:

> flake8 --ignore=E1,E23 path/to/files/

Any ideas on how to do that when flake8 is integrated in the extension?